# Spring WebSocket StompHeaderAccessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

If i execute following code, `sha.getLogin()` and `sha.getPasscode()` outputs null !?
What is wrong with the code?

Client:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect("123","456", function (frame) {
    //...
});
```

Server:

```
@EventListener
private void onSessionConnect(SessionConnectedEvent event)
{
    StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    System.out.println(sha.getLogin());
    System.out.println(sha.getPasscode());
}
```

But if execute following command, the login and passcode is contained.

```
sha.getMessageHeaders().toString()
```

Output (no json):

```
{  
    simpMessageType=CONNECT_ACK,
    simpConnectMessage=GenericMessage[  
        payload=byte[0],
        headers={  
            simpMessageType=CONNECT,
            stompCommand=CONNECT,
            nativeHeaders={  
                login=[123],//<<<Login
                passcode=[PROTECTED],//<<<Passcode
                accept-version=[  
                    1.1,
                    1.0
                ],
                heart-beat=[  
                    10000,
                    10000
                ]
            },
            simpSessionAttributes={},
            simpHeartbeat=[J@4b5cea63,
            stompCredentials=[PROTECTED],
            simpSessionId=xhojby2n
        }
    ],
    simpSessionId=xhojby2n
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use accessor.getPasscode() method instead of accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(PASSWORD_HEADER) 
bacause default StompDecoder protect passcode when setting

```
public void setPasscode(@Nullable String passcode) {
    setNativeHeader(STOMP_PASSCODE_HEADER, passcode);
    protectPasscode();
}

private void protectPasscode() {
    String value = getFirstNativeHeader(STOMP_PASSCODE_HEADER);
    if (value != null && !"PROTECTED".equals(value)) {
        setHeader(CREDENTIALS_HEADER, new StompPasscode(value));
        setNativeHeader(STOMP_PASSCODE_HEADER, "PROTECTED");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is accessing the session data when you call `sha.getLogin()` or `sha.getPasscode()` but your user isn't authenticated on session, when you send connect ACK you need to intercept the message and authenticate user on the session.

Take a look at [Spring Security WebSocket Support & Sessions](https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/16/preview-spring-security-websocket-support-sessions)